# Can't add suffix for per unit (ex: 6.50 / kg) to User Role Pricing Suffix when user role price rule is applied (woocommerce use price plugin)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price, suffix

I can add price suffixes to prices without the user roles price plugin applied through the following function and filter:

```
function jedMj()
{
    global $product;
    $attribute  = 'Jed. mj.';
    $abv        = $product->get_attribute($attribute);
    if(!empty($abv))
    {
       return '/' . $abv;
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'jedMj',50);
add_filter('replace_orignal_price', 'jedMj',50);
```

However, when i add a user based price rule (with the woocommerce pluggin), i can not apply this rule.

You can see the problem in the attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCEXA.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing the priority of the filter from 50 to 10 or 100?

Comment: @mujuonly thanks for the reply! Yes i've just changed the priorities, but no change.  It seems the plugin, woocommerce role based user pricing,  changes what i need to filter, and that, i must try to find.  As you can see in the screenshot, it also changes the style. (i've only applied the rule to the first product, aronija, where you can see the price not only has no suffix but is also styled different, not being in bold.  Thanks for the help and if you can any ideas or need additional info, please feel free to ask! :)

Comment: Add the link to the plugin zip